# Pandas lambda function with Nan support

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, nan

I am trying to write a lambda function in Pandas that checks to see if Col1 is a Nan and if so, uses another column's data.  I am having trouble getting code (below) to compile/execute correctly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1, 2, 3, np.NaN], 'Col2': [7, 8, 9, 10]})  
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x['Col2'] if x['Col1'].isnull() else x['Col1'], axis=1)
```

Does anyone have any good idea on how to write a solution like this with a lambda function or have I exceeded the abilities of lambda?  If not, do you have another solution?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on my large DataFrame, but does work in an example.  Could this be because in my actual data set has a different data type, so fillna won't work correctly?  Both Col1 and Col2 in my actual set are dtype('O') so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need [`pandas.isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) to check if a scalar is `NaN`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1, 2, 3, np.NaN],
                   'Col2': [8, 9, 7, 10]})  
                 
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x['Col2'] if pd.isnull(x['Col1']) else x['Col1'], axis=1)

print(df)
   Col1  Col2
0   1.0     8
1   2.0     9
2   3.0     7
3   NaN    10

print(df2)
0     1.0
1     2.0
2     3.0
3    10.0
dtype: float64
```

But better is use [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].combine_first(df['Col2'])

print(df)
   Col1  Col2
0   1.0     8
1   2.0     9
2   3.0     7
3  10.0    10
```

Another solution with [`Series.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html):

```
df['Col1'].update(df['Col2'])
print(df)
   Col1  Col2
0   8.0     8
1   9.0     9
2   7.0     7
3  10.0    10
```

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean for your else in your first lambda method to be Col1 or Col2?

Comment: Hmmm, I think it is `Col2` - it means get value of col2 if condition is True else get value col1

Comment: But I prefer another solutions if need replace NaNs tby another column.

Comment: Your first two methods work flawlessly.  Just out of curiosity, why do you think it's better to use Series.combine_first rather than a lambda function on the df?

Comment: Because it is faster and vectorized function. But if small dataframe (100 rows), it is no problem. but if `1M` rows, there is huge difference.

Comment: Thanks--appreciate your replies!  Still learning. On my actual data, the lambda function was an order of magnitude slower (8s vs. 0.8s).

Comment: Thank you for comment. `apply` is obviusly used if no pandas function and need write it. Good luck!

Comment: Why `combine_first` instead of `fillna`? `combine_first` works in this case because the two series have the same index, but in other cases, you could get a longer series returned since "Result index will be the union of the two indexes" (from docs).

Comment: @wjandrea - Yes, working with same DataFrame, so same indices. Generally you are right, should be used `fillna`

Answer (score 7):

The correct solution to this problem is:

```
df['Col1'].fillna(df['Col2'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on my large DataFrame, but does work in an example. Could this be because in my actual data set has a different data type, so fillna won't work correctly? Both Col1 and Col2 in my actual set are dtype('O') so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Works for me with object data types also. What's the issue when you use the actual dataset?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [np.isnan()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html)

```
#import numpy as np
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: 2 if np.isnan(x['Col1']) else 1, axis=1)   

df2
Out[1307]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I was trying to round non-NaN values, and this worked whilst `x is np.NaN` didn't:
`df.age.apply(lambda x: x if np.isnan(x) else round(x))`

Comment: @Rafs You should be using Pandas's builtin functions, which handle NaN automatically: `df['age'].round()`. Plus they're much faster. Secondly, don't use `is` on numbers in general; see [numpy NaN not always recognized](/q/52123892/4518341) (which sounds specific to NaN, but the answers explain the more general problem).

Answer (score 2):

Within pandas 0.24.2, I use

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['col_name'] if x[col1] is np.nan else expressions_another, axis=1)
```

because `pd.isnull()` doesn't work.

in my work,I found the following phenomenon,

No running results:

```
df['prop'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['buynumpday'] / x['cnumpday']) if pd.isnull(x['cnumpday']) else np.nan, axis=1)
```

Results exist:

```
df['prop'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['buynumpday'] / x['cnumpday']) if x['cnumpday'] is not np.nan else np.nan, axis=1)
```

So far, I still don't know the deeper reason, but I have these experiences, for object, use `is np.nan()` or `pd.isna()`. For a float, use `np.isnan()` or `pd.isna()`.

Comment: For `is np.nan()`, you meant `is np.nan`, right? I'm not sure if you might have meant `np.isnan()`.

Comment: `pd.isnull()` wasn't working for you because you just made a typo: `if pd.isnull(...)` should have been `if not pd.isnull(...)`. Regarding `is np.nan`, that's not guaranteed to work; see [numpy NaN not always recognized](/q/52123892/4518341) as well as [dataframe.apply(lambda x: x is np.nan) does not work](/q/38531503/4518341). If your column is `object` dtype, that's why it happened to work, but again it's not guaranteed, e.g.: `s = pd.Series([1, np.nan, float('nan')], dtype='object'); s.apply(lambda x: x is np.nan).values` → `[False  True False]` vs `s.isna().values` → `[False  True  True]`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numpy function `where` with condition "Col1 is NaN"

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1, 2, 3, np.NaN], 'Col2': [7, 8, 9, 10]})

df['Col1'] = np.where(pd.isna(df['Col1']), df['Col2'], df['Col1'])
```

Comment: Why? You can just use `.fillna` instead. Even if you don't want to use `.fillna`, why use NumPy when you can use Pandas? `df['Col1'].mask(pd.isna(df['Col1']), df['Col2'])`

Comment: thank you for the correction. The phrase "equals NaN" can be corrected to "is NaN," and the reason is that it's a common way to change one column's value with another based on a specific condition

Comment: Right, I know it's common, but why not use the simpler way?

Comment: I suggest another approach to deal with the issue of filling missing values. In my practice, there are other types of missing values, not only 'n/a.' My suggestion is more universal and can handle various types of missing values or incorrect values.

Comment: Can't `Series.mask` do that too?

Comment: yes, it can, but what's about time of running - my test shows 132 µs ± 455 for df mask and 81.6 µs ± 267 for numpy where