# Pandas: Every value of cell list to lower case

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
# initialize list of lists 
data = [[1, ['ABC', 'pqr']], [2, ['abc', 'XY']], [3, np.nan]] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Val'])
data

    Name  Val
0   1     [ABC, pqr]
1   2     [abc, XY]
2   3     NaN
```

I am trying to convert every value in the list, to it's lower case

```
data['Val'] = data['Val'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if len(x) == 0 else [item.lower() for item in x])
data
```

However I get this error

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Expected final output

```
     Name  Val
0   1     [abc, pqr]
1   2     [abc, xy]
2   3     NaN
```

Comment: You have to escape the `NaN`, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061607/pandas-lambda-function-with-nan-support).

Comment: You can use `lambda x: np.nan if x is np.NaN else [item.lower() for item in x]`.

Comment: Henry, your answer is correct, would appreciate if you can write that as the answer

Comment: @Max I got what mistake I am doing

Comment: I am also getting this error - `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is filter rows without missing values and processing:

```
m = data['Val'].notna()
data.loc[m, 'Val'] = data.loc[m, 'Val'].apply(lambda x: [item.lower() for item in x])
print (data)
   Name         Val
0     1  [abc, pqr]
1     2   [abc, xy]
2     3         NaN
```

Or you can processing only `list`s filtered by `isinstance`:

```
f = lambda x: [item.lower() for item in x] if isinstance(x, list) else np.nan
data['Val'] = data['Val'].apply(f)
print (data)
   Name         Val
0     1  [abc, pqr]
1     2   [abc, xy]
2     3         NaN
```

Comment: I am getting this error also - `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
`

Comment: @HardikGupta - Problem is with sample data?

Comment: problem is with my data, not with sample data, I am unable to reproduce

Comment: the list that I have, it is identifying it as float, and not list

Comment: @HardikGupta - So need change `f = lambda x: [item.lower() for item in x] if isinstance(x, list) else np.nan` to `f = lambda x: [item.lower() for item in x] if not isinstance(x, float) else np.nan` ?

Comment: yes this one worked, what is the issue here, how can I convert the list to be indentified as list itself

Comment: @HardikGupta - Give me a sec.

Comment: @HardikGupta - Can you try `import ast` and then `m = data['Val'].notna()
data.loc[m, 'Val'] = data.loc[m, 'Val'].apply(lambda x: [item.lower() for item in ast.literal_eval(x)])
` ?

Comment: I get this error `ValueError: malformed node or string: ['some..value']`

Comment: @HardikGupta - So it means wrong saved data? How should be processed? is possible replace `...` to emty string ?