# How to combine data from two columns based on multipe conditions in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe where I am trying to combine `Email_x` and `Email_y` to be a column `email`.

1. If both are `NaN` then the result should be `""` or `np.nan`.
2. `Email_y` has a value and `Email_x` does not then use `Email_y` as the result(vice versa).
3. If both have values then take the first one only.

```
                Email_x            Email_y Verification status_x Verification status_y
489   sample3@gmail.com                NaN                 valid                 valid
975    samle4@gmail.com                NaN            accept_all                   NaN
1192                NaN                NaN                   NaN                   NaN
1370  sample5@gmail.com                NaN               unknown                   NaN
2001                NaN                NaN                   NaN                   NaN
2565  sample2@gmail.com  sample2@gmail.com                 valid                   NaN
3900                NaN                NaN                   NaN                   NaN
3998                NaN                NaN                   NaN                   NaN
4192                NaN                NaN                   NaN                   NaN
4757                NaN   sample@gmail.com                   NaN                   NaN
```

I have tried using this but it fails when both have a value and results in both the values being combined.

```
df["email"] = df[["Email_x", "Email_y"]].fillna("").agg(" ".join, axis=1)
```

#### Result:

```
                Email_x            Email_y Verification status_x Verification status_y                                email
489   sample3@gmail.com                NaN                 valid                 valid                   sample3@gmail.com 
975    samle4@gmail.com                NaN            accept_all                   NaN                    samle4@gmail.com 
1192                NaN                NaN                   NaN                   NaN                                     
1370  sample5@gmail.com                NaN               unknown                   NaN                   sample5@gmail.com 
2001                NaN                NaN                   NaN                   NaN                                     
2565  sample2@gmail.com  sample2@gmail.com                 valid                   NaN  sample2@gmail.com sample2@gmail.com
3900                NaN                NaN                   NaN                   NaN                                     
3998                NaN                NaN                   NaN                   NaN                                     
4192                NaN                NaN                   NaN                   NaN                                     
4757                NaN   sample@gmail.com                   NaN                   NaN                     sample@gmail.com
```

#### Expected result:

```
                Email_x            Email_y Verification status_x Verification status_y                                email
489   sample3@gmail.com                NaN                 valid                 valid                   sample3@gmail.com 
975    samle4@gmail.com                NaN            accept_all                   NaN                    samle4@gmail.com 
1192                NaN                NaN                   NaN                   NaN                                     
1370  sample5@gmail.com                NaN               unknown                   NaN                   sample5@gmail.com 
2001                NaN                NaN                   NaN                   NaN                                     
2565  sample2@gmail.com  sample2@gmail.com                 valid                   NaN                    sample2@gmail.com
3900                NaN                NaN                   NaN                   NaN                                     
3998                NaN                NaN                   NaN                   NaN                                     
4192                NaN                NaN                   NaN                   NaN                                     
4757                NaN   sample@gmail.com                   NaN                   NaN                     sample@gmail.com
```

#### Sample dictionary:

```
import numpy as np

a = {
    "Email_x": {
        489: "sample3@gmail.com",
        975: "samle4@gmail.com",
        1192: np.nan,
        1370: "sample5@gmail.com",
        2001: np.nan,
        2565: "sample2@gmail.com",
        3900: np.nan,
        3998: np.nan,
        4192: np.nan,
        4757: np.nan,
    },
    "Email_y": {
        489: np.nan,
        975: np.nan,
        1192: np.nan,
        1370: np.nan,
        2001: np.nan,
        2565: "sample2@gmail.com",
        3900: np.nan,
        3998: np.nan,
        4192: np.nan,
        4757: "sample@gmail.com",
    },
    "Verification status_x": {
        489: "valid",
        975: "accept_all",
        1192: np.nan,
        1370: "unknown",
        2001: np.nan,
        2565: "valid",
        3900: np.nan,
        3998: np.nan,
        4192: np.nan,
        4757: np.nan,
    },
    "Verification status_y": {
        489: "valid",
        975: np.nan,
        1192: np.nan,
        1370: np.nan,
        2001: np.nan,
        2565: np.nan,
        3900: np.nan,
        3998: np.nan,
        4192: np.nan,
        4757: np.nan,
    },
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use `fillna`? Check `df['Email_x'].fillna(df['Email_y'])`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma because the value for `email` can come from `Email_y` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061607/pandas-lambda-function-with-nan-support), which can be achieved with combine_first().

```
df['email'] = df['Email_x'].combine_first(df['Email_y'])
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the value in `Email_y` is needed.

Comment: Did you see in the question the requirement for Email_y?

Comment: If you see the last row of the `expected result` it is shown there and I mentioned it in point 2 but will edit it for better understanding.

Comment: Correction confirmed. Did you run my code? It seems to meet your requirements.

Comment: Yes it does my mistake, works very well thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Via `np.select`

```
condlist = [
    (df.Email_x.isna()) & (~df.Email_y.isna()), # 1st column NAN but 2nd is not 
    (df.Email_y.isna()) & (~df.Email_x.isna()), # 2nd column NAN but 1st is not
    (~df.Email_x.isna()) & (~df.Email_y.isna()) # both is not NAN
]

choicelist = [
    df.Email_y,
    df.Email_x,
    df.Email_x
]

df['Email'] = np.select(condlist,choicelist, default=‘') # default value ''
```

Comment: This works but is a bit length as I need to do this for 4 more columns. If no one comes up with a better answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html), as follows:

```
df['email'] = df['Email_x'].mask(df['Email_x'].isna(), df['Email_y'])
```

It will retain the value of `df['Email_x']` if the condition is false (i.e. not `NaN`) and replace with value of `df['Email_y']` if the condition is true (i.e. `df['Email_x']` is `NaN`).